# Define a canonical map

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(1) Given a set S there is a canonical map σ : S → P(S). Give the deﬁnition of σ and show σ is one-to-one.

In my head, I'm thinking about it like this:

We have a set S and we want to map it to the powerset of S. From what I have heard, a canonical map is a map that is natural, ie, one in which if two people were to define it independently, they end up with the same map independently from one another.

To me, the most natural map to define would be this: 
Let A be a subset of S. Then S is definitely in the powerset of S by definition. Why not map A to its equal in the powerset of S? Is this a correct way to define a canonical map?

It's obviously one to one because the powerset of S is the set of all subsets of S. Thus, the image of A under σ will always match exactly with the same cardinality for A and σ(A)

Comment: Your map is from $S$ to $\mathcal{P}(S)$, not $\mathcal{P}(S)$ to $\mathcal{P}(S)$, so your definition of $\sigma$ can only be on elements of $S$, not subsets of $S$.

Comment: I would think of $s\mapsto\{s\}$

Comment: Oooo okay. I think I see what you are saying. Are you saying I can only map the elements of S to the powerset? Not whole subsets of S? I have sometimes seen people describe images of a subset of the domain in similar ways. I must have made an error.

Comment: In principle $\sigma: S\rightarrow\wp(S)$ maps elements of $S$ (which in most cases are no subsets of $S$) to elements of $\wp(S)$ i.e. to subsets of $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your map takes as input subsets $A \subset S$ and sends them to themselves, then it wouldn't be a map $ \sigma: S \to P(S)$, but instead the identity map $ id: P(S) \to P(S)$ (which, to be fair, is quite natural).

What you need is for each element $s \in S$, some subset of $S$ that "naturally" goes with $s$.